# Cannot find Azure application using az ad app list but it is shown on Azure Enterprise Apps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have got an Azure application that is visible on the GUI using enterprise applications, however when I search using the code below it doesnt work.

`az ad app list --filter "displayname eq 'AzureDataBricks'"`

[image]

The issue here is that I will be granting permissions programmatically, and as such need to extract the application details using the name which in turn gets the application id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`az ad app list` returns Application objects from Graph API.
Enterprise Applications list shows Service Principal objects.

You need to use `az ad sp list` to find the service principal you are looking for.

See this for more info on the difference of applications and service principals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals

Comment: very grateful. it now works when i changed it to `az ad sp lis`